# Angry Birds Seasons "Installation Unsuccessful" -- Help? 

Tags: 2.2-froyo, installation, angry-birds

I have tried several times to install Angry Birds Seasons from the marketplace.  Every time, I get a notification saying "Installation unsuccessful" without anything more descriptive.  Has anyone else run into problems installing it?  Is there any way I can get a more detailed error message explaining what part of installation failed?

HTC Evo 4G

[Update]
7.15GB free on my SD card
196 MB free internally

[Update 2]
I got this error again when attempting to update to the Valentine's day version of Angry Birds Seasons.  Once again, unmounting the SD card and installing it seemed to work successfully.  Further, my save data was still in tact after remounting.

Comment: Have you tried an alternative marketplace, like GetJar?

Comment: @Al GetJar doesn't seem to have Angry Birds Seasons available. Do you know of any alternative marketplaces that offer the game?

Comment: Angry Birds and Angry Birds Seasons both installed straight to my SD card without me ever asking them to for some reason, have you got enough free space on your SD card?

Comment: @GAThrawn 7.15GB free on my SD card, 196MB available internally

Comment: @Dave: GetJar is supposed to be Rovio's official outlet. According to [their blog](http://www.rovio.com/index.php?mact=Blogs,cntnt01,showentry,0&cntnt01entryid=50&cntnt01returnid=58) you should be able to download it from [http://www.getjar.com/angry-birds-seasons](http://www.getjar.com/angry-birds-seasons)

Comment: @Al Hmm, it seems that Angry Birds Seasons doesn't support the Evo.

Comment: I've seen several articles online people referencing playing this on their Evos. Any Evo owners have success installing this? If so, where'd you get it?

Comment: unmounting the sd card worked for me too thanks! so it looks like ALL of my apps are installed with internal disk space. do they eventually start installing on the SD card? Can you manually move apps over to the sd card to free up space on the internal drive?

Comment: I'm glad to hear that unmounting the SD card worked for you.  As for your question, it really should be asked in a separate question on the site.  To provide you some quick feedback, though, there is an app called "App 2 SD" which will allow you to move installed apps onto your memory card.  It may require your phone to be rooted though, I'm not sure.

Comment: @Dave @Bobby : There's an app called [SDMove](http://www.appbrain.com/app/sdmove/com.beaglebros.SDMove) that will facilitate moving already installed apps to the SD card.

Comment: omg yes! unmounting from SD card was the answer! thanks! that was driving me insane

Comment: Now with Angry Birds Rio, I get the install error with the SD card mounted and you can't install with the SD card unmounted.  Not sure what to do next...

Comment: @Alex I had the same problem, and I did the fix found at the end of this post.  I can confirm that it worked, but it seems to have uninstalled or unlinked all the apps I had on my SD card.  Quite strange. http://www.amazon.com/gp/cdp/member-reviews/A89RQ02UGWINV/ref=cm_pdp_rev_title_1?ie=UTF8&sort_by=MostRecentReview#R65O2PCLAF0P9

Comment: @Alex - Also note that all my user data regarding the apps seems to still be present.  Once I reinstall an application (Twidroid, for example), it's like the app was never uninstalled, even though I never added my account back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a very similar issue on my HTC Incredible. Try unmounting the SD card (Menu->Settings->SD & phone storage->"Unmount SD card" on my Incredible) and then installing the app. After it finished installing, you can then remount your SD card.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why, but this worked very well.  Thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad it worked for you. I think I discovered this when I noticed that all of the apps that were unsuccessful were ones which supported or had just been updated to moving to SD.

Comment: do you mean internal or external SD?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most detailed error message you'd be able to get would be the logcat logs.  You can use a terminal emulator on the phone and just type in 'logcat' shortly after the installation, you can use a market app called [aLogcat](http://www.appbrain.com/app/org.jtb.alogcat), or you can use the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) from the computer, open a command prompt and navigate to the tools directory of the SDK and run:

```
adb shell
```

and then

```
logcat
```

Another thing you can check would be to ensure you don't have another version installed.  Sometimes if you download an .apk file and install it using a file manager, then try to download a different version (or even the same version) of the app via the market, it will fail with that error as well.

Answer (score 0):

Find any other app you can and install it. Once installed exit the marketplace. Then go back and try installing the Angry Birds app again. This usually fixes most marketplace issues.

If it still doesn't work go to Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> All -> find the marketplace app and click on it. Then click clear data. Make sure it cleared cache too, if not clear cache. Then reboot. Then run the marketplace and try again.

These tips should help.